The issue of using CSS modules in webpack 5
I want to use CSS modules, but configuring CSS modules in webpack does not take effect，I want to know if there was a mistake in my operation there
I have tried asking ChatGPT how to use CSS module to configure through webpack,But the CSS module provided by it does not take effect at runtime
file directory structure
my-project/
  |-dist/
      |-index.html
  |- src/
  |   |- index.js
  |   |- styles.css
  |- webpack.config.js
  |- package.json

webpack.config.js
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/index.js', 
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'bundle.js' 
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.css$/i,
        use: [
          'style-loader', 
          {
            loader: 'css-loader', 
            options: {
              modules: true
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
};

/src/styles.css
//styles.css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.title {
  color: blue;
}

/src/index.js
// index.js
// index.js
import styles from "./styles.css";

console.log("styles", styles);
document.getElementById("app").innerHTML = `
  <div class="${styles.container}">
    <h1>Hello, CSS Modules!</h1>
  </div>
`;


/dist/index.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>CSS Modules Example</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="app"></div>
  <script src="bundle.js"></script>
</body>
</html>

package.json
{
  "name": "testbar",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack serve --config webpack.config.js --open"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "css-loader": "^7.1.1",
    "style-loader": "^4.0.0",
    "webpack": "^5.91.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^5.1.4",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^5.0.4"
  }
}

This is a screenshot of the console error message after running npm start



Don't you have to include the module keyword in the CSS filename like: style.module.css?

Shouldn't I need to configure moudle.css, modules: true? Isn't CSS module enabled for all files?

try to add this namedExport: false
 module: {
rules: [
  {
    test: /\.css$/i,
    use: [
      'style-loader', 
      {
        loader: 'css-loader', 
        options: {
          namedExport: false,
          modules: true
        }
      }
    ]
  }
]

}

Thank you, the namedExport attribute is indeed possible, but it should be configured in modules.
options:{ modules:{ namedExport: false, }, } 

You should reference the JavaScript bundle file relative to its own location.
In your index.html you are saying  <script src="dist/bundle.js"></script>
and in your webpack.config you are saying
output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'bundle.js' 
  },

since the path of index is in directory 'dist' you are basically telling the program that the source is in MyProject/dist/dist
Change your index.html source to:
<script src="bundle.js"></script>

You can also add a log to see in the console if the styles are loaded correctly in your index.js
import styles from './styles.css';
console.log(styles);  // This should log an object with your class names if correctly configured


Sorry, it's my problem. I mistakenly pasted the path in the HTML when asking the question
I have corrected the error on the issue by printing the styles attribute in index.js and attaching the incorrect image

Take my project config template and use it.

the first thing I notified is that you are using the <script> tag in your HTML to reference JS, you don't need that! Webpack handles it for you.
Loaders queue matter! you must first install style-loader and css-loader and then use them in the right queue first put style-loader and then css-loader like the one provided in the config (make sure you install all plugins, loaders, etc.)
If you want to use this config you must install them using npm or yarn.
This is a YT video tutorial from a perfect instructor that I suggest to watch before doing any projects:

https://youtu.be/IZGNcSuwBZs?si=k89vPQ-brMFZO_2l
const path = require("path");
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const BundleAnalyzerPlugin = require("webpack-bundle-analyzer").BundleAnalyzerPlugin;

module.exports = {
  mode: "development",
  entry: path.resolve(__dirname, "./src/index.js"),
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
    filename: "bundle.js",
    clean: true,
  },
  devtool: "source-map",
  devServer: {
    static: {
      directory: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
    },
    port: 3000,
    hot: true,
    compress: true,
    historyApiFallback: true,
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: ["style-loader", "css-loader"],
      },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader",
          options: {
            presets: ["@babel/preset-env"],
          }
        }
      },
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      title: "Super Calculator",
      filename: "index.html",
      template: "src/template.html",
    }),
    // new BundleAnalyzerPlugin(),
  ]
}

